# How Can I Upload Audio(mp3,ogg,flac) By Using PHP?

Tags: php, image, audio, upload

i'm stuck in here

I do this be before,and by using this PHP code to upload image,but when i try to change it to uploading audio file,it just can't upload it?

My PHP code:(Upload Image[Work]):

```
<?php
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'swf');
if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'arts/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}
}
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
}
```

PHP Code:(Upload Audio[Not Work]):

```
<?php
$allowed = array('mp3', 'ogg', 'flac');
if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
echo '{"status":"success"}';
exit;
}
}
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is you file extension that you want to upload? and give us you given error

Comment: I'm try to let the user upload some 3 type of audio files (mp3,ogg,flac),and i'll put it all in to "upload" folder,and the user can view it on "all.html"

Comment: but when you upload a file, what type of error are show?

Comment: If you can,please help me to edit the code please,because i'm new at PHP please https://www.codepile.net/pile/8Aqk0nJQ

Answer (score 1):

use this code make sure you have the folder on your server

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

$path = "test/music/"; //file to place within the server
$valid_formats1 = array("mp3", "ogg", "flac"); //list of file extention to be accepted
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $file1 = $_FILES['file1']['name']; //input file name in this code is file1
        $size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];

        if(strlen($file1))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $file1);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats1))
                {
                        $actual_image_name = $txt.".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                            //success upload
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";              
                    }
        }
    }
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" method="post" action="text1.php">
<input type="file" name="file1" accept=".ogg,.flac,.mp3" required="required"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: change `$path = "test/music/";` to `$path = "uploads/";`

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$path = "../test/cover/"; //file to place within the server
    $valid_formats1 = array("mp3", "ogg", "flac"); //list of file extention to be accepted
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $file1 = $_FILES['file1']['name']; //input file name in this code is file1
            $size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];

            if(strlen($name2))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $file1);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats1))
                    {
                            $actual_image_name = $txt.".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                                {
                                //success upload
                                }
                            else
                                echo "failed";              
                        }
            }
        }
```

but make sure the form you'll use is correct to support this code asp er include the following

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
```

Comment: also kindly put `accept='mp3', 'ogg', 'flac'` so the input only accept the given fileetype only

Comment: This both of code is not working,and also i'm new at PHP,and i'll put all the music in the one folder call "upload"

Answer (score 0):

Check you php.ini file and make sure upload_max_filesize is enough. If not please increase the upload_max_filesize value. Then try the code bellow

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{      
$path = "uploads/"; //file to place within the server
$valid_formats1 = array("mp3", "ogg", "flac"); //list of file extention to be accepted
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {

        $file1 = $_FILES['file1']['name']; //input file name in this code is file1
        $size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];


                $fileInfo=pathinfo($file1);
                $ext=$fileInfo['extension'];

                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats1))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = uniqid().".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                            //success upload
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";              
                    }else{
                        echo "File Support Not Support";
                    }

    }
}
```

This code is tested so I think it will work fine :)

Comment: Maybe is my HTML code got wrong?,i'll post the HTML code now

Comment: check php.ini and replace it `upload_max_filesize = 500M`